# Barplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I want to draw a barplot that shows bars for industry1 and industry2 at each peak

```
library(ggplot2)
peaks=c(-3:3)
industry1=c(0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.05)
data1=data.frame(peaks,industry1)
industry2=c(0.2,0.15,0.12,0.06,0.12,0.15,0.2)
data2=data.frame(peaks,industry2)
ggplot(data=data1,aes(x=peaks,y=industry1,fill=industry1) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
gg=g+geom_bar(data=data2,aes(x=peaks,y=industry2,col="blue",show_guide=TRUE))
```

If I run it it says that it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
peaks=c(-3:3)
industry1=c(0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.05)
data1=data.frame(peaks,industry1)
industry2=c(0.2,0.15,0.12,0.06,0.12,0.15,0.2)
data2=data.frame(peaks,industry2)
gg = ggplot(data=data1,aes(x=peaks,y=industry1,fill=industry1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
gg
```

the syntax of the call to ggplot() was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?  Otherwise please provide a sample image you are trying to draw.

```
library(ggplot2)
peaks <- c(-3:3)
industry1 <- c(0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.1,0.05)
industry2 <- c(0.2,0.15,0.12,0.06,0.12,0.15,0.2)
dat <- rbind(data.frame(peaks, industry = industry1, ind = "industry1"),
             data.frame(peaks, industry = industry2, ind = "industry2"))
ggplot(dat, aes(peaks, industry, fill = ind)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a merged data frame with both industries.

```
mrg <- merge(data1, data2, by="peaks")
mrgmelt <- reshape2::melt(mrg, id="peaks")
ggplot(mrgmelt, aes(peaks, value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")
```

[image]